# @OneToOne is not fetching in CriteriaBuilder with OpenJPA

Tags: java, jpa, openjpa

Consider following mapping

```
@Table(
    name = "VerkoopOrder"
)
public class VerkoopOrder implements DatabaseEntity, Auditable {

    @Id
    @Column(
        name = "VerkoopOrderId",
        nullable = false
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
        strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY
    )
    public Long getVerkoopOrderId() {
        return this.verkoopOrderId;
    }

    @OneToOne(
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY
    )
    @JoinColumn(
        name = "BetalingsInformatieId"
    )
    public BetalingsInformatie getBetalingsInformatie() {
        return this.betalingsInformatie;
    }
}

@Table(
    name = "BetalingsInformatie"
)
public class BetalingsInformatie implements DatabaseEntity, Auditable {
    @Id
    @Column(
        name = "BetalingsInformatieId",
        nullable = false
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
        strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY
    )
    public Long getBetalingsInformatieId() {
        return this.betalingsInformatieId;
    }

    @OneToOne(
        mappedBy = "betalingsInformatie"
    )
    public VerkoopOrder getVerkoopOrder() {
        return this.verkoopOrder;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to query a list of `VerkoopOrder` with the one to one `BetalingsInformatie` inside with the criteriabuilder

```
    CriteriaBuilder builder = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();

    CriteriaQuery<VerkoopOrder> query = builder.createQuery(VerkoopOrder.class);
    Root<VerkoopOrder> verkoopOrder = query.from(VerkoopOrder.class);
    verkoopOrder.fetch(BETALINGSINFORMATIE, JoinType.LEFT);
    Join<VerkoopOrder, VerkoopOrderLijn> verkoopOrderLijnen = verkoopOrder.join(VERKOOPORDER_LIJNEN);
    verkoopOrder.fetch(VERKOOPORDER_LIJNEN);
    query.select(verkoopOrder);
    query.distinct(true);

    PredicateBuilder predicateBuilder = new PredicateBuilder(builder, verkoopOrder);

    predicateBuilder
            .addEqualPredicate(UUID, criteria.getUuid())
            .addEqualPredicate(AANKOPER_ID, criteria.getAankoperId())
            .addEqualPredicate(verkoopOrderLijnen.get(MSISDN), criteria.getMsisdn())
            .addEqualPredicate(STATUS, criteria.getStatus())
            .addEqualPredicate(verkoopOrderLijnen.get(VERVOERCONTRACT).get(VERVOERCONTRACT_ID), criteria.getVervoerContractId())
            .addDateTimeRangePredicate(TIMESTAMP_CREATED, criteria.getTimestampCreatedStart(), criteria.getTimestampCreatedEnd())
            .addDateTimeRangePredicate(TIMESTAMP_UPDATED, criteria.getTimestampUpdatedStart(), criteria.getTimestampUpdatedEnd());

    query.where(predicateBuilder.build());
    query.orderBy(builder.desc(verkoopOrder.get(TIMESTAMP_UPDATED)));

    TypedQuery<VerkoopOrder> typedQuery = getEntityManager().createQuery(query);

    List<VerkoopOrder> verkoopOrders = typedQuery.getResultList();
```

However the "betalingsInformatie field is always null , (you can also see I'm fetching a list of `VerkoopOrderLijnen` which is filled in just fine as it should.  What else can I try to get the betalingsInformatie ?  I'm dreading having to seperate query each betalinginformatie field in a service instead of straight from a query result.

Does anyone have any insights ?  Keep in mind this is using the OpenJPA implementation not hibernate or eclipselink

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lazy JPA properties can either raise an exception OR they do what they are supposed to do: Load the other entity. You don't see an exception -> the entity must have loaded. Null is probably the correct result. Please check the join column of the particular record you are loading. I guess that no other entity is mapped from there.

Comment: I've checked the database and there should be a record there.  I started my post with my two entities.  VerkoopOrder and BetalingsInformatie (I abbreviated them ofcourse for the purpose of this post).  You can see my exact mapping there.  I checked the console and logs with TRACE logging on and there is no exception

Comment: And this VerkoopOrder has an value in column "BetalingsInformatieId"?

Comment: Yes, it has, but I just saw the service responsible for filling in that field wasn't doing it's job right.  They left it empty, the BetalingsInformatie table actually had records but the reverse field did not.  So I got them to fix that but now I'm struggling with another issue.  

org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: invalid stream header I'm looking into it now

Comment: Make sure your super class "DatabaseEntity" is serializable.

Comment: Thanks Mick, I took it for granted that class would have been Serializable.  It wasn't ...  dealing with legacy code had to dive into the framework and fix it